# Why did URL.createObjectURL start giving my file name as a GUID?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript

This was working fine, and all of the sudden it doesn't.  History of relevant files revealed no obvious changes that would cause it.  Instead of having the real file name, say "upload.txt", I am getting a GUID with no extension.  So the browser can never open the file, and neither can the system when it downloads instead of opens.

It's sending the filename correctly:

[image]

Server-side:

```
[HttpGet("download/{fileId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(int fileId)
    {
        var file = await _fileRepository.GetByIdAsync(fileId).ConfigureAwait(true);
        if (file == null)
            return NotFound();

        var path = _fileService.GetUploadedFilePath(file.FileNameInStorage);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            return NotFound();

        var memory = await PopulateMemoryStream(path).ConfigureAwait(true);
        memory.Position = 0;

        var contentType = FileUtils.GetContentTypeByExtension(file.Extension);
        var displayName = file.OriginalFileName;

        if (!Path.HasExtension(displayName))
            displayName += file.Extension;

        System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = displayName,
            Inline = true  // false = prompt the user for downloading;  true = browser to try to show the file inline
        };
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");

        return File(memory, contentType, displayName);
    }
```

Client-side:

```
  downloadFile(fileId: number): void {
this.fileService.transmitFile(fileId).subscribe(res => {
  const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
  window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
});
  }

transmitFile(fileId: number): any {
return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/file/download/${fileId}`, { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/octet-stream' }, observe: 'response', responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
.pipe(
  map((res) => {
    return new Blob([res.body], { type: res.headers.get('content-type') });
  })
);
```

}

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I thought `URL.createObjectURL` always returned a guid

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I changed the front-end to allow downloading with extensions.  Unfortunately, the files still get the GUID for the file name, but they do come along with the extension when downloaded or open properly in the browser.  You just have to make sure you are setting the right content-type.

```
downloadFile(fileId: number): Observable<HttpResponse<ArrayBuffer>> {
      return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/file/download/${fileId}`, { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/octet-stream' }, observe: 'response', responseType: 'arraybuffer' 
    });
  }

  downloadFile(fileId: number): void {
    this.fileService.downloadFile(fileId).subscribe(res => {
      const blob = new Blob([res.body], { type: res.headers.get('content-type') });
      const file = new File([blob], this.resume.originalFileName, { type: res.headers.get('content-type') });
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
  });
}
```

Bonus: here's the server-side code to set the content type.  Most cases have been tested.

```
public static string GetContentTypeByExtension(string ext)
    {
        switch (ext)
        {
            case ".png":
                return "image/png";
            case ".jpg":
            case ".jpeg":
                return "image/jpeg";
            case ".pdf":
                return "application/pdf";
            case ".doc":
            case ".dot":
            case ".rtf":
                return "application/msword";
            case ".docx":
                return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
            case ".docm":
            case ".dotm":
                return "application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12";
            case ".tif":
            case ".tiff":
                return "image/tiff";
            case ".txt":
                return "text/plain";
            case ".xls":
            case ".xlt":
                return "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            case ".xlsx":
                return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            case ".xltx":
                return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template";
            case ".xlsm":
                return "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12";
            case ".xltm":
                return "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12";
            default:
                return "application/octet-stream";
        }
    }
```